# Update the Task model - RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I started learning Play framework today and it is very good and easy to learn.

I successfully completed the sample provided on their [website](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaTodoList), but I wanted to make some modifications to it.

I wanted to see if could update the label of a particular task, so I followed the following approach

First I added a route to update the data

```
POST    /tasks/:id/update           controllers.Application.updateTask(id: Long)
```

Then I added the following code to `index.scala.html` file

```
 @form(routes.Application.updateTask(task.id)) {
                    <label class="contactLabel">Update note here:</label> 
 @inputText(taskForm("label")) <br />
                }
```

Then I modified Application.java class to

```
public static Result updateTask(Long id) {
        Form<Task> taskForm = Form.form(Task.class).bindFromRequest();
        if (taskForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(views.html.index.render(Task.all(), taskForm));
        } else {
            Task.update(id, taskForm.get());
            return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());
        }
    }
```

Finally in Task.java I added this code

```
public static void update(Long id, Task task) {
        find.ref(id).update(task.label);
    }
```

But when I perform the update operation I get this error

> [RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?]

Needless to say that I commented out

```
 db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
 db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
 ebean.default="models.*"
```

in application.conf since I am already able to save and delete data; but I cannot update the data in the database, why is this happening, did someone try this before, how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update(Long id, Task task)` method on `Task` model should be like below:

```
public static void update(Long id, Task task) {
    task.update(id); // updates this entity, by specifying the entity ID
}
```

Because you passed `task` variable as updated data, you don't need to find reference of `Task` object like you do in `find.ref(id)`. And moreover, `update()` method on `play.db.ebean.Model` class (with one parameter) needs ID of model as parameter.

Hope this help solving your problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have commented out Ebean configuration in application.conf

```
# Ebean configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
# By convention, the default server is named `default`
#
ebean.default="models.*"
```