# Update user in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I'm trying to update an User object in my MySQL database with this code:

```
 public static Result updateUser(){
    User current_user = User.find.byId(request().username());
    String id = current_user.email;
    Form<User> filledForm = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
    filledForm.get().update(id);
    return redirect(routes.DashboardController.dashboard());
}
```

User model:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String name;
    public Date dob;
    public int weight;
    public int height;
    public String gender;

...etc
```

I then get this error: [RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?]

After some testing I've been able to make it work by adding a Long id as @Id instead of using a String email as @Id, but this makes it troublesome to get the logged on user from the session.

So what I'm wondering: Is there a way I can update an user with new fields when it's id is a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment on your question, so I have to write it in an answer. This problem is curious. I have a similiar constellation and use a String as an id and it updates without problems. 
`Is there a way I can update an user with new fields when it's id is a String?` If I understand you right, you want to add new fields to your "user" table in your database while updating it or do you want to update the new fields for this user?
To the exception: Are you sure the user is in the database?
P.S. [Maybe you can try this ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681680/getting-a-runtimeexception-datasource-user-is-null-when-updating-user-model)